# Ler um valor inteiro de um ficheiro

Tags: c

Estou a ler um ficheiro com as seguintes linhas:

```
ADD 50
ADD 30
ADD 10
ADD 12
```

E queria ler apenas os valores inteiros para um vetor.

Eu estou a usar este código:

```
while(EOF)
{
        aux=(char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        if(aux==NULL){
            printf("ERROR, vector\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        aux[i]=fgets(aux,tam);
        i++;
}
```

No entanto não é isto que eu quero porque assim guardo o ADD também.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução bem simples é usar [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) e verificar quantos valores foram lidos, e terminar quando não ler os que interessam:

```
int main() {
    int valor;
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(arquivo, "%*s %d", &valor) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", valor);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O `fscanf` foi utilizado com `%*s` para ler a primeira string, neste caso o `ADD` e descartar o seu valor.

O valor devolvido indica quantos elementos conseguiu ler, que neste caso será `1` caso ainda esteja numa linha válida. Quando chegar ao fim do arquivo a leitura devolve `0` que faz terminar o `while`.

[Documentação para o `fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução seria você percorrer o vetor e ir comparando quando `aux[i] = 'A' aux[i+1] = 'D' e aux[i+2] = 'D'` você guardaria os outros dois valores depois do espaço em branco que há entre o ADD e o número em uma outra variável e poderia multiplicar por 10 e por 1. Tipo `A[1]*10 +A[2] ( 5*10 + 0*1 = 50).`